# Snowflake: copy into SQL with UDF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to call a Javascript UDF in Snowflake while ingesting data via **copy into**.

When I try it, I get an error saying:

SQL Compilation error: Function 'JAVASCRIPT_V' not supported within a COPY

Still, I'm surprised this does not work as my Javascript UDF is only parsing and splitting one data field.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't, but if your UDF is as simple as suggested, and uses the following list of accepted functions, then you can do it with a select in your COPY INTO statement:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-stage.html#supported-functions